# ArrayList c# . Метод Add

Tags: c#, list

При создании списка

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Back
{
    class ArrayList
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
            list1.Add("Hello");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

У меня возникла ошибка :

> C # 'ArrayList' не содержит определения для 'Add', и не может быть
>   найден метод расширения 'Add', принимающий первый аргумент типа
>   'ArrayList' (вам не хватает директивы using или ссылки на сборку?)

Как её решить?

Comment: 1)Называть свои классы так же как и системные классы дурная практика, не делайте так. 2)Не используйте `ArrayList` - это устаревший класс, нужно использовать коллекции с обобщениями, например `List<string>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас ваш класс называется также `ArrayList`. Либо переименуйте ваш класс, либо используйте полное имя типа, включая неймспейсы

```
System.Collections.ArrayList list1 = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
```